# Call action after callback from listener and... cannot dispatch in the middle of dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm in trouble with React and Flux... We have an application that is pretty similar to the new Flux chat example. We have the famous error "cannot dispatch in the middle of dispatch". But, it's hard to us to think in a good way to resolve this problem in some cases.

Our doubt is identical to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/mVbO3H1rICw, but I can't understand very well the solution adopted. As far as I understand, is not a very elegant solution.

Here is the sequence of events:

1. Action A is dispatched;
2. The Store updates it's internal state and emits the change message;
3. A react component X receives the change message (by the callback of the listener) and updates it's state (setState);
4. The component X renders and as part of that a new component Y is mounted too. We choose the component (Y, Z, etc...) to be rendered using the information of the state;
5. The new component Y needs data to display that isn't initially loaded. So we call a API in the componentDidMount() of the component Y, that calls an action B.

Then, with the new dispatcher in the Action B, we have this dispatch error.

If you consider that our application logic have some issue, I can bring some practicals examples to show why this scenario is common for us. Any idea of how refactor this "flux" is very welcome.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use the `waitFor` token from the dispatcher before launching action b (youre using the dispatcher from the `flux` npm module right?). additionally, what can you do is make the ajax call from your store during action A if youre always going to need that data from action b.

```
solution b would look like this in /* store.js */

Dispatcher.register(function(payload){
  switch payload.type {
    case ACTION_A:
      /* do your state logic */
      StoreDataAccessLayer.apiCall()
  }
}
```

where you have a Data Access Layer class / object that wraps your ajax call to the api. using the state from your store as inputs, and calling trigger change from the success function. this is the primitive solution i've seen when using the `flux` npm module if youre not going with `waitFor`

Comment: Hi! I would like to not call an action from the store. "data in a Flux application flows in a single direction": https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Comment: youre not going to use an action to make that api call. youre moving the api into the first action's cycle

Comment: My mistake. I said that because we are dispatching the API results (payload) after call the API, because some components are listening this API call. Our solution is similar: https://github.com/schempy/react-flux-api-calls. And a I cannot dispatch all API calls from Action A because this Store not know what API call will be necessary, because only the components (Y, Z, etc) know that. I will bring two practical examples to the question to clarify the problem.